# Given any symmetric matrix $A$, how to find a diagonal matrix $B$ such that $B \succeq A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, spectral-norm

Given any **symmetric** (not necessarily PSD) matrix $A$, how can we find a good **diagonal matrix** $B$ such that $A \preceq B$? We want each of the diagonal elements of $B$ to be as small as possible.

One possible such matrix I can think of is $\mathrm{diag}(\|A_i\|_1)$, but I don't think it is tight enough. Can we find a better matrix than this? Also, I hope that $B$ depends on the $\ell_2$ norms of $A_i$ instead of the $\ell_1$ norms, or the **eigenstructure** of the matrix $A$. It would be very useful if there are solutions that only needs eigenvalues or singular values, so it is possible to approximate it in almost linear time to the dimension.

The background for this problem is "coordinate-wise smoothness" in convex and non-convex optimization. The global smoothness of a function can be defined as $\sup\|\nabla^2f(x)\|_2$, that is to find a constant $L$ such that $-LI \preceq \nabla^2 f(x) \preceq LI$. I'm looking for a similar way to find the coordinate-wise smoothness efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like the following semidefinite program?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{{\bf x}}{\text{minimize}} & \| {\bf x} \|_1\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{diag} ({\bf x}) \succeq {\bf A}\end{array}$$

---

**Experiments**

Let

$$ {\bf A} := \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$

whose maximal eigenvalue is $\lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) = 3$. Using [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org) to solve the semidefinite program above,

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 2, 1],
              [ 1, 2]])
   
# optimization variables
x = Variable(2)

# optimization problem
optProb  = Problem(Minimize(norm(x,1)), [ diag(x) >> A ])
optProb.solve()

# output
print("Status  = ", optProb.status)
print("Minimum = ", optProb.value )
print("      x = ",       x.value )
```

which outputs

```
Status  =  optimal
Minimum =  5.999999999483413
      x =  [3. 3.]
```

Note that ${\bf x} = \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) \, {\bf 1}_2$. Using ${\bf A} = \mbox{diag}(2,1)$ instead,

```
A = diag(np.array([2,1]))
```

the output is

```
Status  =  optimal
Minimum =  3.0000000000262323
      x =  [2. 1.]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't think about semidefinite programs, so this is helpful. Is there a closed-form solution to this?

Comment: @YanPan Try ${\bf x} = \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) {\bf 1}$. I don't have time to think about this, so please do not assume I am correct.

Comment: @YanPan I updated my answer. It seems that my guess was correct.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo While this solution is true for the optimization problem you consider where there is a uniform bound on $x$, there are other solutions which are tighter and for which the entries of $x$ can be different. An example is with $A=\mathrm{diag}(2,1)$ then, obviously, the best choice for $B$ is $B=A$ and that differs from the solution that $x=(2,2)$ you are giving. In fact, solving the optimization problem for that $A$ yields the solution $(2,1.5)$.

Comment: @KBS You are correct.  Is there a way of salvaging my answer? Maybe minimizing the $1$-norm of $\bf x$ and removing $y$?

Comment: That's what I would do. Minimize the 1-norm of $x$ but showing that it does actually solve the OP problem needs to be proven. I am thinking about how this can be proven.

Comment: @KBS I updated my answer.  In case you have the time and inclination to review it, please let me know if you find any errors.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Your answer looks fine. I did some numerical tests with larger matrices and there is no general answer. I have tried to minimize the 1-norm of $x$, to minimize the 2-norm of $x$. Your previous solution addressed the minimization of an upper-bound of $x$. I also tried to minimize the 1-norm of $x-d$ where $d$ is the vector of eigenvalues of $A$. The idea for that was to be able to deal with negative eigenvalues and values for $x$ which are negative and large in magnitude. Results are similar, yet no solution outperforms the others.

Comment: If we use the fact that $diag(|x|) \succeq diag(x)$, then we can force the entries of $x$ to be non-negative without impacting the objective function. That allows us to change the $||x||_1$ to $\sum x$, adding a constraint $diag(x)\succeq 0$, which is closer to an SDP primal standard form, and might be easier to analyze, if we are looking for some closed form or approximation.